# Trying to shorten every string written inside a range which also has a pivot table to 4 characters long only

Tags: excel, vba

In a range which also includes a pivot table, a macro is required to shorten all the strings. In the pivot table in that range, the row fields, columns fields and report field (all string) are too long to read hence the macro should changes these strings also to their initial 4 left characters only (any other form of shortening will also do).

```
Sub short()
    For Each cell In Selection
        If Isalpha(cell.Value) Then-------separate funtion
            If Len(cell.Value) > 4 Then
                cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 4)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This code doesn't change the row and column headers of the column which are string. Stray values outside pivot table are shortened.

Comment: I believe that you can't change cells that are on pivottables, not like a normal cell, you need to "enter" the pivot table and change the pivotfields and whatever you need.

Comment: As Damian has mentioned, you need to change the `Caption` shown `For Each` of the `PivotItems`